# Predicting outcomes with categorical predictors

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, prediction

My dataset is formulated in a contingency table. My predictor variables are categorical and my dependent variable is the number of observations observed. How do I predict outcomes and find residuals?

I have used the glm function with the link function - poisson. I think I have to use `predict(lm, set, type=probs)`but I'm not sure how to write `'set'`.

The code for my function is

```
backbothfit<-glm(count~school*gender*lecture*course, family=poisson, data=wam)
```

and head(wam) obtains

```
  count   school gender lecture    plan course response
1    37 Suburban Female     Yes College  Maths    Agree
2    27 Suburban Female      No College  Maths    Agree
3    16 Suburban Female     Yes College  Maths Disagree
4    11 Suburban Female      No College  Maths Disagree
5    16 Suburban Female     Yes College    Art    Agree
6    15 Suburban Female      No College    Art    Agree
```

Comment: I wonder if a linear (multiple) regression is the right choice for you. You seem to have a discrete outcome (number of observations), so perhaps Poisson regression or something similar is a better choice. But this depends on that the null hypothesis is that there should be equal number of observations in all combinations of categorical variables. Is that the case? Sounds strange to me. Could you provide a bit more context?

Comment: More context and an idea of what the data look like would be very helpful

Comment: @JonB Sorry, I will edit the question accordingly. I have used the poisson link function. fit<-glm(count~school*gender*lecture*course, family=poisson, data=wam). All predictor variables are binary and categorical. I'm just not sure what code to use to predict the count. For context, school has levels suburban and urban, gender has levels male and female, lecture has levels attend, not attend and course has levels maths and art.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read your reply to my comment, and I'm curious about the purpose and also about whether there isn't a limit to class size? A Poisson distribution assumes no upper limit, and if there is a limit to the number of students in the class, your estimates will be distorted.

However, the answer to your question is simply this:

```
exp(predict(fit))
```

The predict function will give you logarithmed values that need to be exponentiated in order to reflect a count, in your case number of observations. This is because the link function in Poisson regression is logarithmic.

If you want to use your model to predict based on new data you have to create a data frame with variables that have the same names:

```
# creating some simulated data
n <- 100
school <- rbinom(n,1,0.5)
gender <- rbinom(n,1,0.5)
lectures <- rbinom(n,1,0.5)
course <- rbinom(n,1,0.5)
df <- data.frame(school, gender, lectures, course)
```

And then you just use the predict function with the new data frame:

```
exp(predict(fit, df))
```

And for residuals (also on the logarithmic scale), you simply do this:

```
fit$residuals
```

I hope this helps, but please provide a bit more context to your question anyway.

Comment: when using the predict function I obtain: 'Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'school' not found'. From my research it seems to suggest that this means my data does not have 'school' in the columns, however it definitely does and I have checked the case of the letters and they seem to match. Thank you for the residuals.

Comment: Strange. You can update the question with the R code for your model and head(data) and then we can see if anything looks wrong there.

Comment: I have updated the code